# I have a problem with my talent unable to solve it

Tags: talend

In Talend tool I accidentally detach and close the context and components field tabs that are present in the bottom of the diagram now when I run the job I'm unable to see my output also how to solve it anyone know pls let me know

I want to get back that context and components field back

Comment: Reset the perspective/view, it’ll all come back.

Answer (score 0):

From the Menu, `Windows` --> `Show View ...` and then select the view to restore from Talend group :

[image]